# What is the difference between setCalendar and setCalendarDate in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

Previously, I was using setDate to set dates in my query for Hibernate. However, I noticed that setDate only sets the date, not the time. I'm assuming this is where Calendar comes into play, but is setCalendarDate the same as Calendar.getInstance().getTime()?

The [Hibernate documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#setCalendar%28int,%20java.util.Calendar%29) is blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the javadoc inside the class I found:

- setCalendar() - Bind a positional Calendar-valued parameter using the full Timestamp portion.
- setCalendarDate() - Bind a positional Calendar-valued parameter using just the Date portion.

Comment: Even when I inspect the Hibernate Javadoc locally, it still gives me nothing! Thank you for this.